# Code isn't sorting right

Tags: java, sorting

So, I have my code, but my numbers aren't sorting. Is there something I'm missing?

My sort code, no other methods such as printing and such:

```
 public static int[] swapElement (int [] x, int index1, int index2) {
        int t = x[index1];
        x[index1] = x[index2];
        x[index2] = t; 
        return x;
    }
      public static int[] sortArray (int [] x) {
        int index = 0;
        int i=0;

        int[] toSort= new int[x.length];
       for(int m=0;m<x.length;m++){
        index = indexOfMaxInRange(x);
        toSort=swapElement(x,i,index);
        i++;
       }

      return toSort;
    }
      public static int indexOfMaxInRange (int[] x) {
        int max = 0;
        int i=0;
        int maxLocation = 0;
        while(i < x.length) {
            if (x[i] > max) {
                max = x[i];
                maxLocation= i;

            }
             i++;
        }
```

Comment: _and everything is working fine_ Obviously not. Use a debugger to find out where the code behaves differently than what you would expect.

Comment: `swapElement` can be void, as the passed `toSort` argument will be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int m=0;m<x.length;m++){
    index = indexOfMaxInRange(x);
    toSort=swapElement(x,i,index);
    i++;
}
```

Here, you first place the maximum element to the first, then second, then third etc index. The problem is that instead of finding the second-greatest element to the second index, the third-greatest for the third and so on, you're just swapping around the greatest element.

To fix this, I suggest that you make your method `indexOfMaxInRange` live up to its name by specifying a range for it to search instead of having it look through the entire array.

EDIT: per request, here's how you add a lower bound to your method:

```
public static int indexOfMaxInRange (int[] x, int firstIndex) {
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int i=firstIndex; //note! initialize to min instead of 0
    int maxLocation = firstIndex;
    while(i < x.length) {
        if (x[i] > max) {
            max = x[i];
            maxLocation= i;

        }
        i++;
    }
    return maxLocation;
}
```

Notice the changes: the added argument (the first index to search - `0` would mean that the entire array is searched like before) and that `i` is initialized to this new argument.

(I also changed the initial value of `max` to `Integer.MIN_VALUE` to make it work even if the maximum value is negative but that shouldn't concern the original issue you had)

Comment: So how do you suggest I do that? Just add the lower range of it to the current max?

Comment: @NickGatti no it isn't. You don't have a lower range in there, just the array.

Comment: So how would I add that? I'm totally lost.

Comment: @NickGatti, I'll append that to my answer in a minute.

Comment: I tried this, but it's still not sorting. I call indexofMaxInRange with(x,0) in sortArray.

Comment: @NickGatti, but you aren't supposed to search the entire array. The very reason we added that method is that you can use values other than zero as the starting point!

Comment: So what should I set it to? -5?

Comment: Well obviously not, you'll get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` for accessing negative indices. Think, man, think. I won't be answering your questions here for your entire coding career.

Comment: I give up. I've tried every  number in the range, and nothing's working. I'm done.

Comment: Look, trying stuff randomly in hopes it will work is pretty much the worst way to program anything. At least give it a proper shot before calling it quits. Read the code you've got. Run pen-and-paper simulations on what you want your program to do. Use a debugger, if you know how to. Just don't throw random numbers at it and expect it to work, because it won't.